# Git - Creating pull request without forking

Tags: git, github

Been working with git for some time now.
There are plenty tutorials and explanations on git pull request. 
What is it's motivation and etc.

I encounter two scenarios:

**1. Forking git repo**

I view some public git repository and decide that I want to contribute so I:

1. Create a duplicate repository by **Forking** it. For example branch master.
2. Make my changes and commit them.
3. Create a  pull request (Using the GUI for example)
4. select comparison  between original git repository(master branch) to my forked repository.
5. Submit that pull request.

**2. Branch git repo**

Lets say me and my of my team members are working on this git repo.
I working on a certain feature called 'my-feature'. So I do the following:

1. Create a new branch called 'my-feature'.
2. Make my changes. And commit.
3. Create a pull request while selecting master for example as **base** branch and 'my-feature' branch as **compare**
4. Submit the pull request.

Like I said, I understand the way pull requests work in the above examples.

My issue: Mirroring

Yet, I'm working on an assignment in which I was explicitly requested not the fork the repo but to mirror it.

I followed the procedure listed on the github help supplied by the following link:

https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

Basically what I did was to:

create a bare clone of the public repository:

```
 git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
```

mirror push to new repository ( which is on my github account)

```
cd old-repository.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

I made my changes and committed them to my own mirrored copy.
Now how do I create a pull request to the owner of the repository without forking it?

Comment: *“in which I was explicitly requested not the fork the repo but to mirror it”* – But why?!

Comment: Forking and same-repository branches are the official ways of making a pull requests at github. Rejecting the official ways is pointless. Maybe there is some misunderstanding of what actually is needed, then actual task should be described.

Answer (score 1):

As you already pointed out, there are only two ways that allow you to create pull requests: Either from a fork or when you have contributor access to the original repository. If you have neither, then you’re out of luck here.

The only thing you could do is create an issue and ask for a pull (which is kind of a very manual pull request).

There is a related issue about GitHub’s command line interface *hub*, asking for a way to [submit a pull request without a fork](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/424). The comments there discuss how this would work, and various members point out that it won’t be possible without a fork:

> **[j1z0](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/424#issuecomment-28442620):** 
>   If you don't push rights you have to use a fork because the permissions in GitHub are per repo not per branch.
>
> ---
>
> **[mislav](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/424#issuecomment-94412568):**
>   It's only possible to open a pull request without a fork if you have push access to the original repository. Then you can simply push to a new branch in that repo and use `hub pull-request`.
>
> In other cases, you must create a fork with `hub fork` and push to the new remote `git push -u skywinder HEAD` and open a pull request `hub pull-request`.